# Исключение в конструкторе c параметрами Java

Tags: java, исключения, конструктор

Есть конструктор с параметрами, к примеру: конструктор(параметр1, параметр2);
Хочу предотвратить получение в качестве аргумента к параметру2 null. Как это сделать?

Создать собственное исключение и проверять параметр2 на null, в случае null - выбрасывать исключение.Или есть другие способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого существует специальный метод в стандартной библиотеке:

```
public class Foo
    public Foo(String alpha, String beta) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(alpha);
        Objects.requireNonNull(beta, "Honey, have you been forgetting things again?");
    }
}
```

Единственная моя претензия к этому методу - он стреляет NPE, а не IllegalArgumentException, но это ожидаемо (метод проверяет Х на соответствие null, а не валидирует аргумент) и легко исправить собственным хелпером аналогичного значения.

Comment: Данные проверки  Objects.requireNonNull(параметр) пишутся в самом начале конструктора с параметрами?

Comment: @bsuart да, там внутри простой if-блок с исключением

Comment: в смысле if-блок с исключением? можно пример

Comment: @bsuart `if (argument == null) throw new NullPointerException()`